# hibernate.validator.fail_fast Sequence

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

My problem is that i am getting Validation error one by one, But not in sequence.
So can any buddy tell me how to display error, in Sequence according to user need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I hope this is what you want or at least pushs you in the right direction:

In my controller, I have the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/createEntry", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void doAndValidateSomething(@RequestBody @Valid ValidationFormModel, 
                                        HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        testService.doSomething(model);
    } catch (NormalException e) {
        log.error(String.format("Error doing something! Values -> name: %s, address: %s",
                model.getName(), model.getAddress(), e);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

And this is my exception handler (used in controller, too). Note the line `e.getBindingResult.getAllErrors()` here, which gives you a list of all errors. In my case, I decided to use only the first error via `iterator.next()`, but this is just wanted by me, feel free to use `getAllErrors()` only:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public void validationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException e, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.getWriter().append(e.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().iterator().next().getDefaultMessage());
    log.error("Validation failed!", e);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

My model looks somewhat like this:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

public class ValidationFormModel {

    @Length(max=50,min=2, message= "...")
    @NotEmpty(message = "....")
    private String name;

    @Length(max=250,min=1, message= "...")
    private String address;
    //constructor, getters and setters...
}
```

And on client side, I use the following jquery / json to send my data via post and show the actual error. In your error handler, you could change the logic according to your need (I assume you want to show every error directly at the form input field or something):

```
var approveNewSend = function () {
    var newEntry = JSON.stringify({
        name: $('#nameInput').val(),
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/test/createEntry",
        type: "POST",
        data: newEntry,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    })
            .success(function () {
                console.log('yay!');
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                $("#nerrorMessage").html("Error validating: " + data.responseText);
            });
};
```

Hope this helps! Feel free to ask if something's not clear.

Comment: thanks Dominik for you reply.but my problem is to validate entity fields in a sequence as declared in entity class.