# Spring form submission using ajax showing 415 unsupported media type in spring 3.1

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Here is my javascript code on jsp file and json data 
when i do the post request i am getting the 415 unsupported media type error.

```
var user = {"USER_ID":"0","FIRST_NAME":"TEST","MIDDLE_NAME":"TEST","LAST_NAME":"Pathak","ADDRESS":{"ADDRESS_ID":"0","ADDRESS_1":"Shyam Nagar","ADDRESS_2":"DSFSFSD","COUNTRY_ID":"1","STATE_ID":"1","CITY":"1"},"MOBILE_NUMBER":"4444565665","EMAIL_ID":"bharat@gmail.com","LOGIN_NAME":"bharat@gmail.com","PASSWORD":"1234567891234","confpass":"1234567891234"};
    $.ajax({
         dataType: 'json',
         url: 'useradd',
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         type: "POST",
         data: JSON.stringify(user),
         success: function(data) {
              alert(data);
         }
    });
```

Here is my java bean class for user and address with getter and setter method

```
public class UserBean implements Serializable{
    private int USER_ID;
    private String LOGIN_NAME;
    private String FIRST_NAME;
    private String MIDDLE_NAME;
    private String LAST_NAME;
    private String EMAIL_ID;
    private String OLD_PASSWORD;
    private String PASSWORD;
    private String MOBILE_NUMBER;
    private String USER_TYPE;
    private AddressBean ADDRESS;
}

public class AddressBean implements  Serializable{
    private int ADDRESS_ID;
    private int SOURCE_ID;
    private String SOURCE_CODE;
    private String ADDRESS_1;
    private String ADDRESS_2;
    private String CITY;
    private int STATE_ID;
    private int COUNTRY_ID;
}
```

Here is method in my spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/useradd",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json",headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public @ResponseBody String addUser(@RequestBody UserBean userBean,HttpSession session,Model model,HttpServletResponse response){

}
```

Comment: What is it that you support, `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you cannot have both. Also post your getter/setter methods.

Comment: i checked it without header details in controller but getting bad request 400 error

Comment: Which probably comes from wrongly defined getters/setters.

Comment: Here is code for UserBean  http://pastie.org/9199047  and for AddressBean http://pastie.org/9199050 and i am using jackson1.9 for object mapping

Comment: seems you are stringifying strings in your json-object, causing a bad request i think. Just create a "normal" json-object, somewhat like `var newEntry = JSON.stringify({ name: $('#nameInput').val(), });` (see my answer here if you like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464595/hibernate-validator-fail-fast-sequence/20469179#20469179 )